# Turn on/off Bluetooth from shell not from applet

Tags: command-line, bluetooth

Ubuntu 13.04 64 bits, on ELiteBook 8740, gnome desktop with bluetooth-applet shown.

I could not figure out how to turn on and off from shell the Bluetooth and not from the notification bt applet menu. I need to turn on the service and the thing from menu from shell or C.

`service bluetooth start/stop` has noting to do with the applet button menu item because here are the four scenarios I can see.

1. **Service off**, menu item from **applet is off** (shows turn on)

   `bt-device --list`  yields  bluez service is not found
2. **Service on**, (`sudo service bluetooth start`) menu item from **applet is off** (shows turn on)

   `bt-device --list`  yields  rg.bluez.Error.NoSuchAdapter: No such adapter
3. **Service on**, menu item from **applet is on** (shows turn off)

   `bt-device --list`  yields

   ```
   Added devices:
   HMDX JAM (36:8F:E8:07:B2:CA)
   Mint Speaker (5BA5) (01:19:53:4C:5B:A5)
   ```
4. **Service off**, menu item from **applet is on** (shows turn off)

   `bt-device --list`  yields  bluez service is not found

I want to be able to turn on and off the Bluetooth as is being done from the applet button. How can I do this?

Answer (score 107):

The commands you're looking for are:

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```

and

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

To toggle on/off:

```
rfkill toggle bluetooth
```

Comment: Great find! I needed to always use toggle for bluetooth

Comment: thanks Marcus, this unstuck my BT on 18.04! saved me a reboot

Comment: Thank you so much! it is the only workaround for my touchpad-problem that works for me.

Comment: Also works on 20.04, and seems better than stopping / starting the bluetooth service

Comment: Thank you, works on Pop_OS! 22.04. My trackpad was someone turned off - happened only when I am not logged in, otherwise the trackpad worked when I was logged out. After executing your commands I managed to get a hold of my blue tooth mouse and go into the settings to enable the trackpad.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 32):

To stop :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth stop
```

To start :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
```

To restart :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
```

Comment: The use of `service` is preferred over `/etc /init.d/`,  but this works as well.

Comment: this is not correct. turning off bluetooth and stopping the service are different things (most notably, the latter requires sudo permissions).

Answer (score 25):

On systems that use `systemd`, including Ubuntu 15.04 and later:

```
systemctl start bluetooth
```

for turning on Bluetooth

```
systemctl stop bluetooth
```

for turning off Bluetooth

```
systemctl restart bluetooth
```

for restarting Bluetooth

Comment: werewolf_65 - FYI you can omit `.service` because it is assumed if there is no extension (and who likes typing)

Comment: @Zanna alright. Now it is clearer, should have considered to edit the answer like you did...

Comment: I also discovered that I had too reboot, as there was some state info that wasn't reset without that.  Now all is working properly - I hope this helps others.  Beware of attempting to turn on bluetooth through Settings.  And when  working with keyboard/mouse that used a 2.4 Ghz dongle, I needed the bluttooth on, even though I would have thought that as being irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it worked for me: From: [bluetooth keeps turning off in 19.04 after physically and manually turning off bluetooth device, any fix to this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166996/bluetooth-keeps-turning-off-in-19-04-after-physically-and-manually-turning-off-b)

```
$ sudo rmmod btusb
$ sudo modprobe btusb
```

Comment: The only working solution for me. The problem happened after a power failure. No other solution worked for me. But this one turned on my bluetooth like a charm.

Comment: Same here! After a power outage..

Answer (score 3):

If you have [tlp installed](https://linrunner.de/tlp/installation/ubuntu.html) you can use:

```
$ bluetooth on  # To start 
$ bluetooth off # To stop
```

To install TLP:

```
$ sudo apt install tlp
```

Comment: Did you try it yourself. there is no such command.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a quite old question.

> service

command worked for me.

To stop the service -

> service bluetooth stop

To start the service -

> service bluetooth start

Comment: Hi Mitesh. How is your answer better/different from the others? Great you want to contribute though. I recommend you to add this as a comment under existing similar answers, as it is already answered very similarly previously :)

Comment: This answer represents an alternative to "sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth stop" as mentioned in the comments of the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to install `bluez`:

1. Go to http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/bluez-tools/
2. Select your compatible version
3. Install it manually

Comment: Installing extra SW to achieve something built-in is never a good idea and leads to hellish problems down the road. If systemctl stop doesn't work then there are other issues. https://askubuntu.com/a/990973/232407