# bluetooth keeps turning off in 19.04 after physically and manually turning off bluetooth device, any fix to this?

Tags: bluetooth

I keep having my bluetooth turned off in ubuntu 19.04. it happens if I physically turn off or disconnect my Bluetooth speaker. Bluetooth in ubuntu 19.04 won't turn on even if the slider is on "on" mode.  I have to restart ubuntu several times to make it work. I already reinstalled Bluetooth but still, it happens.

anybody here who has the same problem or have a fix for it?

thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

I have the same problem while using bluetooth headset but reloading kernel modules can make it work without restarting.

```bsh
$ sudo rmmod btusb
$ sudo modprobe btusb
```

Comment: Finally something that worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try `rfkill` ([man rfkill](http://manpages.org/rfkill/8))

## hard vs soft block

> Bluetooth in ubuntu 19.04 won't turn on even if the slider is on "on" mode.

There are two kinds of blocking radiodevices: *hard* and *soft*

- You can check events of your device using `rfkill event`
- You can check state of your device(s) using `rfkill list`

## rfkill

> rfkill is a small userspace tool to query the state of the rfkill switches, buttons and subsystem interfaces. Some devices come with a hard switch that lets you kill different types of RF radios: 802.11 / Bluetooth / NFC / UWB / WAN / WIMAX / FM. Some times these buttons may kill more than one RF type. The Linux kernel rfkill subsystem exposes these hardware buttons and lets userspace query its status and set its status through a /dev/rfkill. Given that at times some RF devices do not have hardware rfkill buttons rfkill the Linux kernel also exposes software rfkill capabilities that allows userspace to mimic a hardware rfkill event and turn on or off RF. ([source](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/rfkill))

### `rfkill event`

1. Open terminal
2. Run command `rfkill event`
3. Try to switch your device on|off
4. Some command output should appear

### `rfkill list`

1. Open terminal
2. Run command `rfkill list`
3. You'll see states of your devices

- the command is rfkill event.

Comment: tried using rfkill but its a hit or miss also,i still have to restart ubuntu or go to windows then restart to ubuntu for bluetooth work again

Comment: @shootsatf8 sorry, but you didn't show neither any output of your commands nor some other symptoms. Please explain your case a bit more detailed.

Comment: @Yasen hi, I've a similar problem. Here are my outputs, do you have any guess?

```
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: @FSp, your connectivity is enabled