# Bluetooth automatically turns off on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04, bluetooth, power-management

When I turn my airbuds on and connect them to my laptop they keep turning on and off without even asking me and sometimes Wifi does this too.

In Settings it's written that Wifi and Bluetooth can automatically turn off to save power, but I don't want to save power. I can't find any way to to turn this annoying option off.

Please help me out, I just want it to stop automatically turning off Wifi and Bluetooth. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have tried is leaving the Settings application open under Bluetooth. Does not "fix" the issue, but it does helps make the disconnect much less bad!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

From: [bluetooth keeps turning off in 19.04 after physically and manually turning off bluetooth device, any fix to this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166996/bluetooth-keeps-turning-off-in-19-04-after-physically-and-manually-turning-off-b)

```
sudo rmmod btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```