# GUI option hiding anywhere for bluetooth rmmod btusb and modprobe btusb

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I landed on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166996/bluetooth-keeps-turning-off-in-19-04-after-physically-and-manually-turning-off-b/1167726#1167726?newreg=b08016506b6d49fc8ccb4cac125d87d1) post after typing into a search engine 'Ubuntu bluetooth keeps switching off immediately after switching on'

The current top answer worked for me and solved my problem:

```
$ sudo rmmod btusb
$ sudo modprobe btusb
```

I've been using Ubuntu as my laptop for just over a year and would probably be considered novice compared to most on this forum. I don't understand what that solution is or how it works, but other than bookmarking the post and copy pasting the solution everytime I have this problem, I wanted to ask if there's a more permanent solution or even a gui option that achieves the same result?

Comment: These sites may help with info about rmmod and modprobe :
*https://www.tecmint.com/load-and-unload-kernel-modules-in-linux/* and *https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rmmod-command-in-linux-with-examples/*. you can also try Blueman for it's GUI

Comment: I use blue man, great app!